# Rails 3.1 in place edits: gem that works, or roll my own?

Tags: rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.1, edit-in-place

I'm using the latest RC of Rails 3.1 and I can't seem to find a gem that works for in place editing. I tried the [in_place_editing](https://rubygems.org/gems/in_place_editing) gem, but I just get

```
undefined method `in_place_edit_for' for ItemsController:Class
```

errors. The 6 lines of doc with that gem don't really help me much, so I'm guessing it's 3.1 compatibility issue. If there's something obvious I'm missing I'd love to hear about it. [Update: I just tried it with a rails 3.0.10 app, and it doesn't work there either -- same `undefined method` error.]

Other gems I looked at like [best_in_place](https://rubygems.org/gems/best_in_place) haven't been updated for 3.1 either.

Any tips on gems that might work? Or should I just wait it out as punishment for being on the edge?

Should I think about rolling my own? I'm not quite sure where to start with that.

Thanks,
Stewart

Comment: I'm using the 3.1.0 release now, and still having the same problems. The closest I've come is using the jeditable-rails gem, which actually works on the page, but then I can't figure out how to interface the AJAX it creates with my controllers. The documentation for the gem is lacking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go with best_in_place. Ryan Bate's has made a screencast on this. This may help you get started: http://railscasts.com/episodes/302-in-place-editing

https://rubygems.org/gems/best_in_place Says gem is compatible with Rails 3.1. Don't see why you would have problems.